Change filter date format of MUI Data Grid
I'm currently working with a Material-UI (MUI) Data Grid and have encountered a challenge with the date format in the filter field. By default, the filter date field seems to display dates in the DD.MM.YYYY format. However, for my project, I need the dates to be displayed and filtered using the YYYY.MM.DD format instead.

I tried to look into the documentation, but could not figure out how I can do it.
